# Split 32-bit int into 2 signed 16-bit shorts

Tags: bit-manipulation, mips, mips32

Is there any simple way to split the value of 32-bit registers into 2 signed 16-bit shorts each?

I thought about this:

```
#t0 holds the 32bit value containing the 2 signed shorts

sra  $v0, $t0, 16  #extract the 1st signed short and put it in v0
li   $t1, 0xffff   #create a mask
and  $v1, $t0, $t1 #extract the 2nd signed short and put it in v1
```

But that would destroy the sign of the second value right? Is there an simple way that doesn't involve masking the sign of the 2 values in another register and move it to v1 after?

Comment: For the lower half: `sll $v1,$t0,16` / `sra $v1,$v1,16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sign-extend the low bits you need to shift left and then right back

```
sll $v1, $t0, 16
sra $v1, $v1, 16
```

Demo on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+f(int+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(short)x%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:40.227409166532226,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-mavx2+-march%3Dhaswell',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:mips5,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'0'),fontScale:14,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O2',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'MIPS+gcc+5.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:59.772590833467795,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:1,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)